# How to calculate linear (not sin) output out of increasing value

Tags: javascript, game-physics

I have an increasing value 1 to 10000. I can put this in a `sin` function to get values like a sin output.

Now I want a linear output, that when I give this value as input it gives me output like this: Actually the values has to be in `0..1` range

`0 .1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9 .8 .7 .6 .5 .4 .3 .2 .1 0`

How can I do this fast math way

#### Long

Actually I want a period of zeros and then a sudden burst to 1 and than a calm down to 0 again. I thought if I get the above version I can put that in an easing function to get this result:

`0 0 0 0 0 0 .1 .2 .4 .8 .9 1 .9 .8 .4 .2 .1`

Comment: looks almost like a triangular wave https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave

Comment: What about firing two for loops? One for upwards and second one for downwards?

Answer (score -1):

A non performant slow way to do this is:

```
const linear = (() => {
  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    res.push(i / 100);
  }
  for (let i = 100; i > 0; i--) {
    res.push(i / 100);
  }


  return t => res[Math.round(t) % res.length];
})();

const easing = t => {
  return .04 * t / (--t) * Math.sin(25 * t);
};
```

Use it like `easing(linear(t))`

Comment: This should be in the question: it shows precisely what you're looking for, whereas the current question is contradictory and vague.

Comment: By the way, I'm pretty sure that what makes this "non performant" and "slow" is the `easing` function, not the `linear` function. So the question is probably wrong to begin with.

Comment: I am looking for a best practice, there should be a name and a known solution to my problem @ruakh.

Comment: I'm not sure why you ended your last comment with `@ruakh.`; so far as I can tell, your comment has nothing to do with either of mine?